# "We'll Meet Again" in end credits - is there an explanation for why?

Tags: analysis, kong-skull-island, monsterverse

At the end of the film, Kong: Skull Island, they play a short section of the song "[We'll Meet Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We'll_Meet_Again)."

My initial instincts were that it is a post-modern nod to the idea that King Kong will continue to be remade so long as humans watch movies, but then I recalled that the song is also featured in [Dr. Strangelove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove) and wondered if it might be a reference to a planned sequel involving nuking Skull Island.

Comment: So, I'm assuming you missed the end-credits scene.

Comment: I saw that but I don't think that is the only meaning.  Great point though.  I will amend the question.

Comment: I really don't get this kind of reasoning: "very popular song X is used in completely unrelated movie Y, conclusion: Z". That song is used in numerous movies, so why single out one and then make up a theory out of whole cloth? Also, this: http://www.refinery29.com/2017/03/144358/kong-skull-island-movie-after-credits-godzilla-scene

Comment: @DukeZhou - I'm not talking about John C. Reilly's character returning home, because that connection is rather obvious (he is the one who starts singing the song, after all). What I mean is the scene __after__ the credits finish.

Comment: @BCdotWEB   Because it has the distinct feeling of post-modernism. The script specifically mentions an earlier attempt to nuke the island.  Of all the other movies the song is used in, Dr. Strangelove is arguably the most significant.  I may be incorrect, as Oliver_C has indicated a post-credit scene I've missed.

Comment: @Oliver_C I missed that scene.  If you could fill me in (with the >! spoiler tag, I'd be grateful.)

Comment: @DukeZhou - If you want to know what happens in that scene you can click __BCdotWEB's__ link, or [this one](http://www.slashfilm.com/kong-skull-island-credits-scene-explained/), which includes comments from Jordan Vogt-Roberts (the director).

Comment: You are seriously clutching at straws that aren't there. As if Dr Strangelove is the only film ever to have mentioned nukes. Also, nukes are the *cause* of Godzilla.

Comment: @DukeZhou - I don't know what's actually going to happen in the sequel. Maybe Skull Island will be nuked. So, as your question stands right now, I can't answer it.

Comment: Not sure what the question is actually asking.  Can you reword it and make the question clear?

Comment: Why is your last paragraph in italics? It makes no sense... is it a quote? It reads like a review of the film, which doesn't belong in your question.

Comment: "We'll Meet Again" isn't some obscure song only used in Dr. Strangelove, it is a well-known classic. So looking for a connection between the two movies based solely on the use of that song is simply absurd, even more so when you start to fantasize about it being a hint about its sequels while ignoring the evidence the film presents as well as what is known about future movies.

Comment: Why are you making up nonsensical statements and attribute them to me? As I've stated before: "We'll Meet Again" isn't some obscure song only used in Dr. Strangelove, it is a well-known classic. Who did Kubrick reference by using the song? Oh wait, he simply used it because it was a classic. Ditto here. Why is this so hard to comprehend? Why do you insist on tying these two movies together on this flimsiest of evidence and extrapolating a theory which is debunked by existing reporting? There is no there there.

Comment: <sigh> Once again you are making up statements that I've never said. Were there references in KSI? Yes. ***Obvious ones.*** But "mention of nukes + using We'll Meet Again = Dr Strangelove" is just nonsense, especially when you then use this to "predict" the sequel.

Comment: You are now lying about your own words: "it might be a reference to a planned sequel involving nuking Skull Island". Also, none of what you said is in any way related to Dr Strangelove. I never denied the presence of winks to other movies, that's something you made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slashfilm](http://www.slashfilm.com/kong-skull-island-credits-scene-explained/) provides a good breakdown of the ending of Kong: Skull Island, which is corroborated at [Refinery 29](http://www.refinery29.com/2017/03/144358/kong-skull-island-movie-after-credits-godzilla-scene).

*Special thanks to Oliver_C and BCdotWEB for providing these links, and thus providing the key to the answer I was looking for, as I did not think to remain until the credits ended!*

Kong: Skull Island is heavily referential, most notably to Apocalypse Now and Moby Dick, although there may well be references I didn't catch. The inclusion of this specific song is likely not random, as it constitutes one of the most famous scenes in cinema: [Ending of Dr. Strangelove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15YgdrhrCM8).

The support for this idea comes via the Kong sequel teasers:

> "Kong: Skull Island isn’t just a new take on the classic movie monster that originated on the big screen back in 1933. It’s also the second film in the new cinematic universe that launched with Gareth Edwards’ new take on Godzilla in 2014. Though Kong: Skull Island takes place all the way back in 1973, it prominently features the government organization Monarch, the same department that kept the existence of Godzilla and other monsters under wraps in Edwards’ film." 
> "They’ve found evidence of other monsters existing. A film reel begins to play, and while it doesn’t show any actual pictures of these monsters, there are photos of cave paintings that reveal not just Godzilla, but also the silhouettes of other monsters."
>  "The final image shows a painting of Godzilla fighting with a three-headed monster and the scene cuts to black…and we hear the iconic, shrieking roar of Godzilla."

<sub>Source: [Slashfilm](http://www.slashfilm.com/kong-skull-island-credits-scene-explained/)</sub>

> "This post-movie scene merely confirmed what fans of big monster action movies have long hoped for: Godzilla's returning in 2019 for Godzilla King of Monsters."
> "Even more importantly, the teaser officially confirms that King Kong and Godzilla exist in the same reality. By linking Kong and Godzilla, Legendary Pictures has given birth to a whole new universe of action movies. By 2020, the monsters will duke it out in their very own movie, Godzilla vs. Kong."

<sub>Source: [Refinery29](http://www.slashfilm.com/kong-skull-island-credits-scene-explained/)</sub>

Nukes were mentioned several times in Kong: Skull Island, including the implication that the US had tried to nuke the island in decades past, and may well attempt it again.

It is highly likely the inclusion of that specific song at that specific point in the film is a reference to [Dr. Strangelove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove#Awards_and_honors) because:

> [Godzilla is an allegory on the dangers of nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla#Cultural_impact), which is also the main theme of Dr. Strangelove.